# ReactJS app inside Laravel's public folder .htaccess configurations

Tags: reactjs, laravel, .htaccess, react-router

I am hosting a React application inside the public directory of a Laravel app where:

```
/public_html/
             app
             bootstrap
             config
             database
             public <--- React App Here
                 static <--- Belongs to React
                 index.html <--- Belongs to React
                 index.php <--- Belongs to Laravel
                 .htaccess <--- htaccess (2)
             .htaccess <--- htaccess (1)
             other laravel folders
             .
             .
             .
```

The root directory's `.htaccess` htaccess (1) contents are below, it's responsible for removing the `/public` from the Laravel app's route:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Laravel's public folder `.htaccess` htaccess (2) contents are below, I never touched them:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The problem is that when I access the app via `https://myapp.com` React takes control over the routing, and redirects me to the `https://myapp.com/home` view, while if I refresh the page, Laravel's route takes control and shows a Laravel 404 error that `/home` route doesn't exist.

How can I fix .htaccess file to ignore React's routes and just load the index.html file while keeping Laravel's `/api` routes working? Since all the React app routes are using Laravel's API controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a RewriteCond for /api that redirects to php, the rest should go to the html file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, by doing this, all /api calls are returning the HTML file contents now.

Comment: The HTML file? It should load the php file. Maybe remove the trailing / from ^/api/, updated my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, even removing the trailing slash and using /api only returned the contents of the index.html file.

Comment: Try moving the /api block to the bottom, I've updated my answer

Comment: Same result, `<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head>.......`, it's loading the HTML file.

Comment: Just a quick note that one of the requests I am trying is `https://mywebsite.com/api/users/login` .. it should go to the laravel app through the index.php file, but it returns the HTML file of react instead.

Comment: If a test the htaccess file with https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ with that url it says it will load the php file

Comment: Yeah I see that, but take a look at the structure and htaccess file here https://ibb.co/GtMK0FS and take a look at the response that is coming here https://ibb.co/Ct0WD1J, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe the .htaccess (1) file in the root folder is affecting it?

Comment: Don't think so, if I add the redirect with /public it still works. What happens if you add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api` to the conditions for the index.html?

Comment: Thanks again for your following up John, what happened again after adding the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api` is getting the same result, the HTML file contents, I am sure the edits are being saved correctly as my other edits on the file work fine.

Comment: Any idea, please? 

Comment: Hmm if after that last rule the html file is still loaded it doesn't seem like the .htaccess file is loaded, could be file permissions (should be 644 if i remember correctly).
You are using apache right? As web server that hosts your site, asking just to be sure as nginx doesn't load .htaccess files

Comment: Yes, im running on apache. I am sure the htaccess file works because if i type something wrong there the whole website stops working.

Comment: John you deserve the bounty, but my problem is not solved yet, can you please assist me somehow by chat?

Comment: Yes no problem, and I had another idea. Maybe your VirtualHost config is in the way somehow

Comment: I'm on a shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you my example, I was fallen into the same problem recently, try this if it helps you...

I have a folder name server and then in server I have my backend api in laravel and the react part is in the public_html folder of the hosting.

the below configurations worked for me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =YourDomainHere
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Final rule for back end index
RewriteRule ^server/public/index\.php$ - [L]
# Redirect to back end index
RewriteRule ^api$ server/public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^api/.* server/public/index.php [L]

# the below code will help you while you are addressing your react's index.html

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```